# Home folder name with Unicode characters?

Tags: users, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does character 'ä' in usernames cause bugs in linux systems?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21013/does-character-a-in-usernames-cause-bugs-in-linux-systems)

Is it possible to create a user with a Unicode login name (and home folder name) ?  For instance, in Arch Linux, I try:

```
$ useradd -d /home/andréas -m   -g users  -s /bin/bash andréas
useradd: invalid user name 'andréas'
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to enable such a thing, weither it be with another *nix or some custom kernel compilation.

If it's not possible, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder name isn't the problem, it's the user name. User names can have only a very restricted character set (letters, dashes and digits only); see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux).

The why however, isn't explained very clearly. Maybe someone else can chime in,